# What we call this codeblock

Tags: c#

I wonder what we call the block : `public Circle(double radius)`  . is this Constructor ? If yes then is it possible to write  `Radius = radius;` in the body of contructor ? Or it is only a function ?

```
 using System;
    namespace PatternMatchingDemo
    {
        public class Shape
        {
            public const float PI = 3.14f;
        }
        public class Circle : Shape
        {
            public double Radius { get; }
            public Circle(double radius)
            {
                Radius = radius;
            }
```

Comment: yes it's a constructor and yes you can do `Radius = radius;`

Comment: You should start by reading a good introductory book. It's more productive for you than looking at code and start guessing what basic syntax means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's a constructor 
A constructor is a special method that is used to initialize objects. The advantage of a constructor, is that it is called when an object of a class is created.

You code constructor has a parameter constructors can also take parameters, which is used to initialize fields.

This link more detail about constructors

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-constructors/